# returning mysql datetime as hours ago, days ago etc using UTC time?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

i am using the following script which converts my standard DATETIME stamp to display as hours ago, days ago etc.

```
    <?php require_once 'config.php'; ?>

<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kaliningrad');
function pretty_relative_time($time) {
 if ($time !== intval($time)) { $time = strtotime($time); }
 $d = time() - $time;
 if ($time < strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00')) - 60*60*24*3) {
 $format = 'F j, Y';
 if (date('Y') !== date('Y', $time)) {
$format .= ", Y";
 }
 return date($format, $time);
 }
 if ($d >= 60*60*24) {
 $day = 'Yesterday';
 if (date('l', time() - 60*60*24) !== date('l', $time)) { $day = date('l', $time); }
 return $day . " at " . date('g:ia', $time);
 }
 if ($d >= 60*60*2) { return intval($d / (60*60)) . " hours ago"; }
 if ($d >= 60*60) { return "less than an hour ago"; }
 if ($d >= 60*2) { return intval($d / 60) . " minutes ago"; }
 if ($d >= 60) { return "about a minute ago"; }
 if ($d >= 2) { return intval($d) . " seconds ago"; }
 return "a few seconds ago";
}
?>
```

I then call the function like so:

```
echo pretty_relative_time($row['user_blocked_timestamp']);
```

this works fine on local host however when tested on my server i get the following error:

```
It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are required to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone set() function.
```

Can someone please explain why i am getting this error and what i can do to fix it.

so far i am storing all my DATETIME stamps using:

```
UTC_TIMESTAMP() rather than now()
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just do what the error tells you, on the top of the page put the default timezone.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kaliningrad');
```

You can find all the timezone names here. 
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: i have tried that but i still get the same error. Please see updated answer to see newly tried code. thanks

Comment: @JamesGayle Why are you putting the actual date in the function as well? You don't have to return it like that. You should just post the code I posted above at the top of the page. Not in the function.

Comment: apologies but i am new to php and ok i have updated my answer with your suggestion and still am getting the same error

Comment: Are you calling the funciton in the same file as where you declared the default timezone?

Comment: No the code above is in my time.php file and i call it from my login.php page using <?php include 'time.php'; ?>

Comment: @JamesGayle Then you wanna call the function on that file.

Comment: nope tried that as well and still getting same error.